# Eichler orders in the quaternion.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, division-algebras

Suppose $D$ be a quaternion over the number field $K$.

$\Bbb{Definition.}$ The Eichler ordre $R$ of level $N$ in $D$ is defined as the one which satisfies the following equality with the completion $K_v$ of $K$ at all places $v$$\colon$
\begin{equation*}
R \otimes_{O_K} \!{O_{K_v}} \cong \Bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}\label{matrix} 
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\in {\mathrm M}_2(O_{K_v}) ~|~ c ~\equiv~ 0~ {\mathrm{mod}} ~ N \Bigg\}.
\end{equation*}

Let us write $\widehat{R} = R \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z}$, where $\widehat{\Bbb Z} = \underset{n > 1}{\varprojlim} \, {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}$. In the similar manner, we define $\widehat{D} \colon= D \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z}$.

Let us once and for all choose one Eichler ordre $R$ of level $N$ and denote by $N(\widehat{R}^{\times})$ the normaliser of $\widehat{R}^{\times}$ in $(\widehat{D})^{\times}$. We say to Eichler ordres $R$ and $R'$ are conjugate to each other if there is some element $a \in D$ such that $R' = aRa^{-1}$.

Q. Why conjugate classes of all Eichler ordres of level $N$ in $D$ is classified by $N(\widehat{R}^{\times})\setminus(\widehat{D})^{\times}/D^{\times}$?

Comment: Do you understand how it goes locally?

Comment: I guess that for all Eichler ordres $R$ of level $N$, $\widehat{R}$ are conjugate to each other up to some element $a \in \widehat{D}$. I wonder how this unique compact subring $\widehat{R} \subset \widehat{D}$ has to do with the type number of $R$ in $D$ over $K$.

Comment: This is actually Proposition 13 (d) in the following website: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/SC9-Orders.pdf